# Inserting PHP code in Drupal 7 basic page

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal, this may be a simple question. I have created a Basic Page in Drupal 7 Admin Panel with form as its content.

Now, I need to add some php code in form action field to process the form data. Below is my HTML code for your reference :

```
 <form class="small_indend" id="popup_form" name="popup_form">
 <div class="form-group"><label class="font_size" for="name">1. Name</label>
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="col-md-8 width_device1"><input class="form-control"  id="name" name="name" onblur="if(value=='') value='Name'" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name') { this.value=''; }" onkeypress="return AllowAlphabetOnly(event)" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="Name" />
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Is there any module to do this? Or the only way is to use js?

Comment: you can create template for your block or page.

Comment: Yes it can be done based on node id right?

Comment: yes. You are on right track. :)

Comment: OK thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to use php code in your content,

1. Enable "PHP filter" module. It will add "PHP Code" as one of the selectable options for "Text format" in Long Text fields.
2. While creating the page, select "PHP Code" as the "Text format" for the field.

Note: It will work perfectly for Long Text fields.